# Error while altering ssas cube with alter xmla

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

Getting following error when trying to alter cube :
Message: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Unspecified error. 
Message: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Communication link failure; 08S01; TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. i could resolve this issue by changing the log on as for sql server analysis services from local system to domain/user account.